# How to change font size for bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

I want to use a smaller font size for the bibliography, e.g., \footnotesize. What is the easiest way to achieve this? I currently do `\renewenvironment{thebibliography}...` and copy the definition from report.cls but with the `\footnotesize` inserted in. However, that seems to be a bit of a hack, so I'm looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: I think your current method is the cleanest. If you find yourself doing this a lot, you might consider moving it from your document's preamble to a personal style (`.sty`) file.

Comment: the ams document classes define `\bibliofont` for this purpose.  it's worth checking the document class you are using before redefining `thebibliography`, but if a suitable command isn't available, your method is appropriate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With BibLatex, how do I make the fontsize of the bibliography smaller?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205432/with-biblatex-how-do-i-make-the-fontsize-of-the-bibliography-smaller)

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio While I can see that there is a overlap between the two questions, I would not close this question here as a duplicate of the one you linked to. If at all I would do it the other way round. The question here has answers for all bibliography packages. The question you linked to is specific to `biblatex`. Plus the question here has more views, votes, and is older.

Comment: @moewe, sounds fair, I agree with you.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

First I have to say that you should avoid fiddling with font sizes in order to squish more text into a document. Conferences and journals often discourage such formatting hacks; some might even reject papers found to be doing this.

Anyway, if you *still* need to to this for whatever reason, the easiest way I found is to write something like

```
{\footnotesize
\bibliography{bibfile}}
```

Comment: I thought this would also change the font size of the "References" heading, but to my surprise it doesn't. Nice!

Comment: I wouldn't consider bibliographies typeset in a smaller size as a formatting hack - I've seen it quite often in professionally typeset books.

Comment: @JitseNiesen: Unfortunately it changed size of the heading in my case.

Comment: @nimcap, which packages are you using? if you cannot solve your problem, you might try to ask a new question.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro: I did as the original asker's way, changed the sty file.

Comment: This does not work with `\fontsize{5cm}{5.5cm}`. Only part of the bibliography takes the new size formatting... :/

Comment: This command reduces changed the font (or decreased spacing between the lines) in the section just above the `\bibliography{}`

Answer (score 156):

Using the [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package you could also write

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
```

(Personally I'd use `\small` instead of `\footnotesize`.)

Comment: seems that it does not work with `\footcite`?

Comment: This will lose the process of lowercasing letters of reference titles...

Comment: To mirror the exact definition of `biblatex.def` I would use `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\footnotesize}`.

Comment: In Rmarkdown, the following worked for me: ```\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\small}```.

Answer (score 71):

And if you use the [`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package:

```
\def\bibfont{\footnotesize}
```

Comment: This way looks the most elegant for me, thanks

Comment: If you are having problems with getting itshapes, you can use `\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}`

Comment: should this be now a `\renewcommand` ? it did not work for me.

Answer (score 33):

Using [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer)+[`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex%5C) you could also write

```
\frame[shrink=50] {\printbibliography}
```

And using [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer)+[`bibtex`](http://www.bibtex.org/) you could write accordingly

```
\frame[shrink=50] {\bibliography{bibfile}}
```

Comment: @Exocom how do we use shrink with allowframebreaks

Comment: `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks, shrink=60]
    \bibliography{bibfile}
    \bibliographystyle{style}
\end{frame}`

Comment: Very useful for `beamer`, where for me, `\footnotesize` wasn't doing anything. Also, a thing to note, higher the number given to shrink, higher it shrinks. So, a value of 20 does not mean it shrinks "to" 20% but "by" 20%.