# Reducing bibliography font size

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

I am using the `thebibliography` command in LaTeX to generate a bibliography under a "References" heading at the end of a paper. My bibliography is not stored in a separate TeX file, but rather is just typed under the command `\begin{thebibliography}` at the end of the paper. I would like to reduce the font size of my bibliography. I tried using the command suggested in the first answer here [How to change font size for bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329/how-to-change-font-size-for-bibliography), but it did not seem to work for me. It appears to be intended for documents with a separate bibliography file, which I do not have. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can reduce the font size with `thebibliography`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Enclose the `thebibliography` environment in a group and switch to `\footnotesize` within the group. EDIT: Or even better, switch to `\footnotesize` *inside* the `thebibliography` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

Some text in \verb|\normalsize| \cite{test}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\footnotesize

\bibitem{test} A bibliography item in \verb|\footnotesize|.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there any way to reduce the spacing between bib items?

Comment: Add `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` after `\footnotesize`.

Comment: How to reduce the size of the word References ?