# How to change font size in Bibliography using BibTex with apacite package

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

I am using BibTex for my references with the style package apacite. Within the document I am using the font size 12pt, but would like to use only 11pt fontsize for the references. Sorry, but my document guidelines ask for this. I know it has been discussed in some threads, but all the proposed solutions didn't work in my case. I am using Tex Live 2012.

Here a short code example:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headings=normal]{scrartcl}
   \usepackage{apacite}
   \begin{document}
   \section{Assignment}
   In this short paper, an analytical overview on the structure of two 
   scientific papers \cite{Kaplanidou2010, Humphreys2011} is provided.
   The analytical focus is taken on research paradigms, research types,
   research designs and methods of the mentioned articles.
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
  \bibliography{Biblio_Perso}
  \end{document}
```

Here is the content of the file Biblio_Perso.bib:

```
@article{Humphreys2011,
title={{Who cares where I play? Linking reputation with the golfing capital
and the implication for golf destinations}},
author={Humphreys, C.},
journal={Journal of Sport \& Tourism},
volume={16},
number={2},
pages={105--128},
year={2011},
publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}


@article{Kaplanidou2010,
title={Predicting behavioral intentions of active event sport tourists: The    
case of a small-scale recurring sports event},
author={Kyriaki Kaplanidou and Gibson, H.J.},
journal={Journal of Sport \& Tourism},
volume={15},
number={2},
pages={163--179},
year={2010},
publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Yours!

Comment: Could you please link to the specific questions that provide solutions which don't work for you?

Comment: Have you, for example, tried loading `apacite` with the `natbibapa` class option (`\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`) and following this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1442/8057 ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you know where and how to read the answer can be so simple.

Just one thing:
The entry "References" disappeared from my `\tableofcontents`. I tested and it's due to the `natbibapa` option.

Any recommondations to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Magnus: Have you tried the `bibtotoc` option for `documentclass`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329/21591

Answer (score 8):

You have two choices.

### First choice: `apacite` without `natbib`

The bibliography environment is typeset according to `\bibliographytypesize`, which defaults to `\normalsize`; so it's sufficient to change this macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headings=normal]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{apacite}
% \small is 11pt if the base font is 12pt
\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\small}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Assignment}
In this short paper, an analytical overview on the structure of two 
scientific papers \cite{Kaplanidou2010, Humphreys2011} is provided.
The analytical focus is taken on research paradigms, research types,
research designs and methods of the mentioned articles.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Biblio_Perso}
\end{document}
```

### Second choice: `apacite` with `natbib`

The bibliography is typeset according to `\bibfont`; however `natbib` redefines the title making procedure, so we need to issue the command that puts the reference section in the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headings=normal]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
  \section*{\refname\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Assignment}
In this short paper, an analytical overview on the structure of two 
scientific papers \cite{Kaplanidou2010, Humphreys2011} is provided.
The analytical focus is taken on research paradigms, research types,
research designs and methods of the mentioned articles.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Biblio_Perso}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
\begingroup
\def\bibfont{\small}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
%\clearpage  %if it should start on a new page
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliography{Biblio_Perso}
\endgroup
```

Comment: @egreg : You were right!
The right solution is to use `\renewcommand{\bibliographytypesize}{\small}` between `bibliographystyle{...}` and `bibliography{...}`