# How to change font of the references in Lyx?

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I want to change my IEEE references style in Lyx, because I have all the letters somewhat capitalized:

[image: A reference]

How to change it to a normal font?

**Edit** (bib file snippet added):

```
@article{borodin_architectural_????,
title = {Architectural Approach to the Multisource Health Monitoring Application Design},
author = {Borodin, Alexander and Zavyalova, Yulia and Zakharov, Alexei and Yamushev, Igor},
file = {[PDF] iš fruct.org:/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/g7561egsh.default/zotero/storage/PAA3RH6M/Borodin et al. - Architectural Approach to the Multisource Health M.pdf:application/pdf}
```

}

Comment: How are they written in the `.bib` file? If they're written with lowercase letters there, then the bibliography style is the likely culprit.

Comment: I added the snippet of `.bib` file.

Comment: Well, it's obviously in lowercase, so I would guess the bibliography style is to blame.You don't say which one you use though. Have you tried any others? If this happens regardless of bibstyle then something else is up, and a complete example would be nice: take a copy of your document, and remove content as you can without removing the problem.  Then add the `.lyx` file (it's just plain text), or at the least the exported LaTeX code to your question.

Comment: For example use apa citing: `\bibliographystyle{newapa}` before adding your bibliography. It comes with `\usepackage{natbib}`

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79615/how-to-change-font-size-in-bibliography-using-bibtex-with-apacite-package

Comment: @API Note that he's using LyX, so the code is (sort of) hidden from the user, and not directly editable.

Comment: Click on the `BixTeX Generated Bibliography` box. In the pop-up window in Style menu select `plain`. If then all is still in upper case, you should have some command before `BixTeX Generated Bibliography` box causing this. Please construct a MWE with a empty LyX file with only one cite and box (includig the `IEEEexample` database  and your style) and post the generated LaTeX source (`View`>`View Source`> copy & paste).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your replies, now I solved the issue. The problem was that I accidentally put my bibliography in a section and I haven't seen it until I looked in the source view:

```
\section*{\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\string"MyBibliography\string"}
}
```

I just changed to standard:

```
\bibliography{\string"MyBibliography\string"}
```