# How to make the font larger for bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

I want to make the font for bibliography (BibTeX) larger, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you want the whole bibliography to have a larger font size, or just the title?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so we can see which documentclass etc. you are using.

Comment: Is it this that you want? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329/how-to-change-font-size-for-bibliography

Comment: @mafp I wish the bibliography can have larger font size, as there is a need to filled up a page for the bibliography, if the font size is 10pt, i would like to set it to 11pt.

Comment: @Christian that seems to discuss how to make it smaller, i would want to make it larger

Comment: @Christian I am using \documentclass[9pt]{sig-alternate}

Comment: The link of @Christian is fine, just replace `\footnotesize` with `\large`. However, I don't think it is a good idea to increase the font size just to fill the page. You could increase `\bibitemsep` to get more space between the bibliography entries.