# Changing Font Size of Bibliography Heading

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, fontsize

In [How to change font size for bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329/how-to-change-font-size-for-bibliography), people discuss changing the Bibliography heading font size without changing the size of the "References" heading.

I would like to also make the "References" heading be normal size.

How do I do this?

I would prefer to use the bibtex style alpha. I am using the class article.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,headings=normal]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{general}

\begin{document}

...


\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm). Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) we can play with - it will encourage users to answer too. Do you mean the bibligraphy style by "alpha"? I can't think of anything else but seems legit to check - alpha can mean so many things... btw which documentclass are you trying to use?

Comment: Hi, it appears you've created two accounts, [the one that created the question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39535/user39535) and [the one that edited it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39536/user39536). You can have StackExchange merge them, by following the instructions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: The `general` package is not available; since the `headings=normal` option is not standard, I guess it has to do with this package. So it's impossible to answer without a pointer to the package.