# Moving BibTeX References to the same Margin as the Rest of the Text

Tags: bibtex, margins

When I do BibTeX references using the `alpha` style, they are slightly shifted to the left from the rest of the text. How can I align them with the document body?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,headings=normal]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{general}
\begin{document}
We see \cite{hs}.
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

My BibTeX file has this:

```
@ARTICLE{hs,
  AUTHOR = {Yonatan Harpaz and Tomer Schlank},
  TITLE = {Homotopy Obstructions to Rational Points},
  YEAR = {2011},
  NOTE = {arXiv:1110.0164 [math.AG]},
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "they are slightly shifted to the left from the rest of the text". By "they" do you mean the labels of the bib entries? Do you want the entire entry, and not just the first line, to be set to the full width of the textblock?

Comment: Yes. I just want all the entries to be the same margin as the text. Right now, the text is 1in from the boundary of the page, whereas the bibliography is less than one inch from it.

Comment: The problem is that there is 1 inch from the leftmost text to the left boundary of the page, whereas there is less than one inch from the bibliography items to the left boundary of the page.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like you've come across an incompatibility between `babel` -- specifically, its `hebrew`-related code -- and the `alpha` bibliography style. (The incorrect indentation goes away if the `hebrew` option is removed, but that's not a real solution, right?!) I'm afraid I have no suggestion for fixing this bug.

Comment: Thanks! Problem Solved! (There was actually no hebrew) Now to deal with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142467/changing-font-size-of-bibliography-heading

Comment: Based on the comments, this is unclear, particularly as the `general` package is not available.