# How to adjust layout of the first page of index?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, idxlayout

In my book I have a page with index. The content of it exceeds one page only with two items, so I would like to decrease some vertical spaces on this page to hold the whole index on this page.

By default the layout of the first index page is set with `\indexsetup{level=\chapter*}`, and then the index looks as follows:

[image]
[image]

When I change the index layout with `\indexsetup{level=\section*}` then all index records fall into a single page (what I want), but the title word "Index" is too small:

[image]

I tried to find the solution in `idxlayout` package manual - without any effect. I found something that seems to be connected with the problem, but I don't know how to use it: `\renewcommand*{\indexstheadcase}{\Huge}` (?). A bit similar question is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142467/changing-font-size-of-bibliography-heading) (without answer).

My code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=8cm,
top=10mm,bottom=10mm,left=10mm,right=10mm,
headsep=3mm,footskip=6mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

% header and footer contetnt adjustment
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}    % page header emptying
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% title page layout adjustment
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-5pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15pt}{\Huge}

\indexsetup{level=\section*}
\makeindex[columnsep=8mm]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
The Roadrunner\index{Roadrunner} run on long distances.
The Coyotewill\index{Coyote} has lower continuous po\-wer.

Cookiemonster\index{Cookiemonster} can eat safe.

AAA\index{AAA} aaa\index{aaa} BBB\index{BBB} bbb\index{bbb}.

CCC\index{CCC} ccc\index{ccc} DDD\index{DDD} ddd\index{ddd}.
\clearpage

\chapter{Some section}
This is an exemplary text\index{text}
which serves to demonstration the problem with index layout\index{index}.

More text on the page\index{page}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change `\titlespacing` for `\chapter` just before `\printindex`.

Comment: @egreg Thx. That solves my problem at all. But I wonder how to manage with the similar problem it which are few indexes along the book (not only on the last page)...

Comment: I see no reason for changing the chapter style. Anyway, what does prevent you from restoring the spacing afterwards?

Comment: @egreg OK. Thx. Your answer is very helpful for me. I understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason for changing the chapter style.

Anyway, you can change `\titlespacing` before `\printindex` and if necessary, restore it afterwards.

You can of course define a wrapper command:

```
\newcommand{\myprintindex}[1][]{%
  % change the spacing
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-25pt}{10pt}% <-- adjust here
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \printindex
  \else
    \printindex[#1]%
  \fi
  % restore
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-5pt}{20pt}%
}
```

Comment: Thx. In MWE it works very well ...but now I am looking for a reason why it doesn't affect the index page layout in the book I am working with...

Comment: How to manage with the problem in which my code have commented the line with the \titleformat command?

Comment: @forrest Sorry, but I can't see your code.

Comment: I thought about the code which I put in my question. Why putting `%` before `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{15pt}{\Huge}` causes that method doesn't work?

Comment: @forrest “Doesn't work” in what sense? I did it and found no problem at all.

Comment: I put your piece of code into "MWE" from my question, then I replaced `\printindex` with yours `\myprintindex` and I checked if changing -25pt value affects the index page layout. In my case it does only if the line witch `\titleformat` is not commented.
I'm afraid that my present problem is not a LaTeX problem but I don't see something...

Comment: If you don't use `\titleformat`, then titlesec does nothing to chapters