# LyX: Index title does not align with section titles

Tags: lyx, titlesec, indexing

When adding an index in a LyX document, the title "Index" (or its modified name) does not vertically align with other section titles in the output. There is more vertical space above it. This can be seen in the [German](https://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/LyX/Manuals/2.3/de/UserGuide.pdf) and the [English](https://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/LyX/Manuals/2.3/en/UserGuide.pdf)) manuals, compare pp. 193 and 191 or pp. 177 and 175 respectively.

Could this be related to the two-column-layout of the index?
There was a similar question about changing the layout of the first page of the index: [How to adjust layout of the first page of index?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359615/how-to-adjust-layout-of-the-first-page-of-index)

I wouldn't want to modify the layout of the index title but to match it with other section pages (that I defined with titlesec). Could `titlesec` modify the index title in LyX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
```

to the preamble gives the desired layout of the first page and title of the index.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).