# How to change font of bibliography with no extra text appeared before it?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, fontsize

I want to change font of bibliography (using package `natbib`). I found some solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329/how-to-change-font-size-for-bibliography). They worked for me, but the text size (e.g.: `\small` or `10pt`) started to appear as text before bibliography. I want to get rid this text off.
Solution 1:

```
{\footnotesize small
\bibliography{references}}
```

Solution 2:

```
\def\bibfont{\footnotesize 10pt}
```

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, english]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Intoduction}
\citep{Moran2008}.
{\footnotesize small
\bibliography{references}}
\end{document}
```

Part of output file:

1 Intoduction

(Moran et al., 2008). small

Bibliography

Comment: `\footnotesize` is enough, remove the *small* or the *10pt*.