# Font size of references list in Pandoc

Tags: r, pandoc, markdown

I am using `RMarkdown` to make a document with references from a `.bib` file as shown below. How can change the font size and line spacing of the references list printed at the end of the page

```
---
author: "Keniajin
bibliography: bibliography.bib
csl: vancouver.csl
documentclass: article
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.5
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    includes:
      in_header: mystyle.sty
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329/how-to-change-font-size-for-bibliography is for bibtex, but nothing there seems to work in pandoc (even adding them into the template).

Answer (score 6):

You simply can't with pandoc. However, there is a workaround. Just after the last title `#References` for example, you can add some tex directly and then render the file using the `-s` flag.

Here is a MWE (using pandoc instead of Rmd):

```
---
bibliography: ./source/library.bib
---

# Lorem Ipsum

"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet [@chou2003interactivity], consectetur, adipisci velit..."

# References

\footnotesize
```

All references will have smaller size with this.