# Problem with changing size of biblography

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

I followed the suggestion from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329/how-to-change-font-size-for-bibliography) as:

`{\footnotesize
\bibliography{bibfile}}`

The font size is smaller now, but there is a problem as showing below

[image]

How can I fix the problem (by adding some space between the header title and the first reference?)

Thanks a lot

**Solution**

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452114/section-heading-for-references-and-the-actual-citations-are-squished-together-in)

`\enlargethispage{10pt}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
{\footnotesize
\bibliography{sigproc}}`

Comment: `\vspace{-1cm}`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it works. I added your command after ``\bibliographystyle{abbrv}`` and before my command in the first post but nothing changed.

Comment: Please show us a short, compilable code to show us, how you build your bibliography. Do not forget and add please two bib entrys!

Comment: the best place to make the change for `\footnotesize` is *after* the `\begin{thebibliography}` command that is generated as part of the `.bbl` file from bibtex.  that, in turn, means that a patch to the environment definition in the document class is probably needed.  but first, look into the document class code, and see if there's a definition for `\bibliofont` or similar; all the ams classes contain such a definition to make such changes possible and reliable.

Comment: Hello there, a workable version could be found at: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/57f4c015739d198874504a8c (in fact, it is original ACM conference proceedings template)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I provided a working example with CLS file, but I could not figure out where do the font size for bibliography section is defined. Could you help?

Comment: can you please identify the document class being used *in the question*?  that will make it much easier to help.  (not everyone is able to look at other sites.)

Comment: It's this one https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/article-templates/sig-alternate-05-2015.cls