Changing font size of references in LaTex format
I have a paper written in LaTex format. I have defined \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} and
\usepackage{cite} in the preamble. I have created a library.bib file and added my references in Bibtex format then used /cite{} in text for citations. At the end of the paper I have included \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} and \bibliography{library}. I succesfully see the references at the end of my paper yet I want to change the font size of the references to 9 pt. I tried using biblatex package and added \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small} but it threw many errors and didn't really work. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Instead of describing how you document looks like, please try to come up with a minimal working example (MWE) that shows the error you have. If you are not able to create such a small code snippet, at least post the exact message from the first error in your log file.

Did you try this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343/42803 ?
